# How can i render a block before 'page-title-wrapper' div

Tags: magento2

I want to render a block(phtml file) that contains a logo in `<a>` tag before the `page-title-wrapper` div. I wanted to do this in `/sales/order/print/` page.

What I tried in my `sales_order_print.xml` file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="sales_order_print_renderers" />
    <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
    <update handle="print" />
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.title">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.order.print.logo" template="Magento_Theme::invoice-logo.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`page-title-wrapper` div is something that is rendered by magento globally on every page, containing the page-title.

The logo shows up but it renders inside the `page-title-wrapper` instead of above it. I have attached the Screenshot below.

[image]

How can i bring the logo in `<a>` tag above/top of the `page-title-wrapper` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display a block before the `page.main.title` container, you will need to refer to the container's parent and use the `before` attribute within your block.
If you examine the codebase, you will notice that the parent of the `page.main.title` container is `columns.top` container:
`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</referenceContainer>
```

Your code should look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.order.print.logo" template="Magento_Sales::invoice-logo.phtml" before="page.main.title" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

When customizing a layout within the `Magento_Sales` module, we should place the `phtml` template file within this module rather than the `Magento_Theme` module. Therefore, in the code above, I have updated the `phtml` template value to `Magento_Sales::invoice-logo.phtml`.

Also, when extending a layout, it's **important** to **not copy all layout instructions** into your file. This will prevent any potential issues when upgrading your Magento version and will save you time in the future as you will not need to update related code. Therefore, in your code, the following lines are redundant:

```
<update handle="sales_order_print_renderers" />
<update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
<update handle="print" />
```

Read more about `before` and `after` attributes at https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/xml-instructions/#before-and-after-attributes

"Extend a layout" documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/extend/

Answer (score 1):

Putting it inside of that referenceContainer will output it indeed inside of the page.main.title.

I guess the page.main.title is by default inserted into the content container (check the vendor/magento directory for this of the project), meaning that adding the logo also in that container could solve it. Make sure to set the before attribute correct as well, like:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.order.print.logo" template="Magento_Theme::invoice-logo.phtml" before="page.main.title" />
</referenceContainer>
```

If not, than perhaps adding it to the body of the page with a before:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.order.print.logo" template="Magento_Theme::invoice-logo.phtml" before="page.main.title" />
</body>
```